# Can't scope to iframe

Tags: javascript

I am trying to scope browser-monkey to iframe, but it seems to be querying parent document instead.

```js
const paymentFormIframe = browserMonkey.scope(
  document.querySelector('.credit-card-form iframe')
)
await paymentFormIframe.find('p').shouldHave({text: `Paying ${amount}`})
```

iframe seems to exist: 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok, turns out iframe wasn't there after all. More precisely, it wasn't there at the time of the above code was run.

So I changed my code to make sure iframe exists before going further and all works as expected:

```js
const iframe = await this.find('.credit-card-form iframe').element()
const paymentFormIframe = browserMonkey.scope(iframe)
await paymentFormIframe.find('p').shouldHave({text: `Paying ${amount}`})
```